# Saving outlook emails in folders and subfolder to local drive and preserve original directory error

Tags: vba, outlook, path

I used below code to save outlook emails in folders and subfolder to local drive and preserve original directory.

```
Private objFileSystem As Object
 
Private Sub ExportFolderWithAllItems()
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim strPath As String
 
    'Specify the local folder where to save the emails
    strPath = "C:\Users\qiaoqiao\"
 
    Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
    'Select a Outlook PST file or Outlook folder
    Set objFolder = Outlook.Application.Session.PickFolder
 
    Call ProcessFolders(objFolder, strPath)
 
    MsgBox "Email saving is completed", vbExclamation
End Sub
 
Private Sub ProcessFolders(objCurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder, strCurrentPath As String)
    Dim objItem As Object
    Dim strSubject, strFileName, strFilePath As String
    Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.Folder
 
    'Create local folder based on Outlook mailbox folder directory
    strCurrentPath = strCurrentPath & ModifyName(objCurrentFolder.Name)
    objFileSystem.CreateFolder strCurrentPath
 
    For Each objItem In objCurrentFolder.Items
        strSubject = ModifyName(objItem.Subject)
        strFileName = strSubject & ".msg"
        strFilePath = strCurrentPath & "\" & strFileName
        i = 0
        Do Until False
           strFilePath = strCurrentPath & "\" & strFileName
           'Check if there exist emails with the same subject
           If objFileSystem.FileExists(strFilePath) Then
              'Add order number to the end of the subject
              i = i + 1
              strFileName = strSubject & " (" & i & ").msg"
           Else
              Exit Do
          End If
        Loop
 
        'Save as MSG file
        'On Error Resume Next
        'Debug.Print Len(strFilePath)
        objItem.SaveAs strFilePath, olMSG
    Next
 
    'Process subfolders recursively
    If objCurrentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
       For Each objSubfolder In objCurrentFolder.Folders
           Call ProcessFolders(objSubfolder, strCurrentPath & "\")
       Next
    End If
End Sub

Function ModifyName(folderName As String) As String
'Dim folderName As String
'In order to save emails in the same directory as in Outlook,
'when creating the folders in local drive,
'the folder name must not contain some special characters
      folderName = Replace(folderName, ":", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "|", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, ",", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "'", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "(", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, ")", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "~", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "*", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "?", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "/", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, "\", "")
      folderName = Replace(folderName, """", "")
      folderName = Trim(folderName)
      'folderName = Replace(folderName, Chr(34), "")
      ModifyName = folderName
End Function
```

However, since there are many layers of folders, so the strFilePath become very long, and it gave me a runtime error saying Operation failed.

Can anyone please advise me how to solve this issue? thank you in advance!!!

Comment: I did some research and learnt that this might be resolved by adding prefix "\\?\" to the path. So I modified the strPath = "\\?\C:\Users\qiaoqiao\". But still this did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please list any long file path string which gives the error, so we could check how it works?

Comment: Did you try to save the item manually with the same file path string in Outlook? Do you get any error messages in that case?

Comment: I have to  use * to avoid data leakage per company policy. The path is something like this, I have remove/replace the special characters in email subject: "\\?\C:\Users\qiaoqiao\OneDrive - ***\***\1_CLN-Archive\CLN Archives- 2022\2022 03 Mar\11Mar22 1y EURUSD Call Spread ******* - *** ***** CH1167234***\RE [Outstanding]1y EURUSD Call Spread ******* -**-****-***-*** [**-****-***-***@***.com]; Sinha *****-A [*****-a.sinha@***.com]; ******* Anna [anna.*******@***.com]; **-****-***-SPG [sh-****-***-spg@***.com]; DL-***-SPG [d  ***** CH1167234***  11M.msg"

Comment: Do you get any error messages in Outlook if you save the message with the same file path?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev
Yes, outlook will also give me an error. I guess it also caused by the long path.

Comment: That's it! Glad we were able to find the cause. Please see my post for more information.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev But how can we solve this long path issue？I can't change the path or email name, they have to remain what they should be.

Answer (score 0):

In Office products there is a limit to the number of characters in the file path. This error message occurs when you save or open a file if the path to the file (including the file name) exceeds 218 characters. This limitation includes three characters representing the drive, the characters in folder names, the backslash character between folders, and the characters in the file name.

Make sure that the path to the file contains fewer than 219 characters. To do this, use one of the following methods:

- Rename the file so that it has a shorter name.
- Rename one or more folders that contain the file so that they have shorter names.
- Move the file to a folder with a shorter path name.

Note that if you enter 255 characters in the File Name box in the
Save As dialog box, and click OK, you will receive the following error message:

```
The path you entered, "<path>", is too long. Enter a shorter path.
```

Also, if you attempt to save a file and the path exceeds 255 characters, you will receive the following error message:

```
The file could not be accessed. Try one of the following:

- Make sure the specified folder exists.
- Make sure the folder that contains the file is not read-only.
- Make sure the file name does not contain any of the following characters: < > ? [ ] : | *.
- Make sure the file/path name doesn't contain more than 218 characters.
```